# How to retrieve images from a dynamic folder inside databse? in PHP

Tags: php, directory

I am new in PHP, I am student. 
I am doing my project for Online Hotel website, In which i have to create a backend for admin control and a front end. 
I have created almost everything, but having little problem to retrieve images from dynamically added folder from databse. 
I have a table with name 'hotel' , that contains many fields. 
I have done php for upload  images according to newly added hotel, all the images will go and store in databse with making a new folder on each hotel added. 
The problem is, When I wanted to pull those images in front end of my website, images are pulled randomly-not in proper order for particular and related hotel. 
The case is it should strictly need to pull according from its relevant directory.

At the time of upload images in databse, All the images is save in this fashion: 
Hotel Fewa Holiday Inn, Lakeside-6/double_dlx.jpg ( here, Hotel Fewa Holiday Inn and Lakeside-6 are table (hotel) field name, double_dlx.jpg is file name)

My code is : I know, there is some mistake. If some one can help me out of here, will be appreciated. 
[This code retrieve images from subdirectories randomly, actually i need images of relevent hotel's ]

```
<?php

$dir = '/*/';
$directory = "../administrator/images/hotels/*/";
$images = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg");
$imgs = '';
foreach($images as $image){ $imgs[] = "$image"; }
shuffle($imgs);
$imgs = array_slice($imgs, 0, 1);
//display images
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
echo "<img src='$img' height='150' width='150' /> ";
}  ?>
```

Comment: Can you clearly state your directory structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to retrieve the list of hotel ids from your database and show the corresponding images. So first, you're going to have to connect to your database. Assuming that it is a MYSQL database, you should do something like:

**edit:** added some debugging info based on the comments.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'swaminarayan');

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

/* Select queries return a resultset */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT name, hotel_address FROM hotel")) {
    /* Print number of rows returned */
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);
    $directory = "../administrator/images/hotels/";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {            
        $search_dir = "$directory/{$row['name']}{$row['hotel_address']}";
        if ($path = realpath($search_dir)) {
            echo "Globbing for images in $path\n";
        }
        else {
            echo "Current working directory: " . getcwd();
        }
        $images = glob("$search_dir/*.jpg");
        if (empty($images)) {
            echo "No images found\n";
        }
        sort($images);
        //display images
        foreach ($images as $img) {
            echo "<img src='$img' height='150' width='150' /> ";
        }
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

[mysqli::query documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

The `sort` function takes an optional second argument, with which you can specify how you would like to sort your array (numerically, alphabetically, etc.). See the [sort documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) for more details.

Comment: Dear master: Chinnu R!
I hope you understand my problem. 
I did tried as you have said, But, same results again. 
I cannot give a fixed hotel_id, because, I have to print hundreds of hotel in a row with their related picture from (dynamically added folder) databse.
Do you want me to send you my database as well?

These are the field in my DB: 
hotel_id city_id country_id name photo1 photo2 photo3 photo4 photo5 hotel_address phone1 phone2 phone3 phone4 contact_email room_description area_description travel_description food_description rates_added
(Folder creates with name & hotel_address fields

Comment: Did you mean to comment on my answer, or on the one given by Chinnu R?

Comment: Thank you for your support , but I have following Error: Notice: Undefined property: mysqli_result::$fetch_field in C:\wamp\www\swaminarayant\hotel_frontend\index.php on line 218

On using:
above code. as

Comment: <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'swaminarayan');
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT hotel_id FROM hotel");
$directory = "../administrator/images/hotels/";
while ($id = $result->fetch_field)  
{   
     ?>                    
                    <article class="one-fourth">                             <figure>
     <?php 
     $images = glob("$directory/$id/*.jpg");
    // sort the $images array if you want
    sort($images);
    //display images
    foreach ($images as $img) {
        echo "<img src='$img' height='150' width='150' /> ";
    }

?>
<?php }

Comment: `fetch_field()` should be a method, not a property. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I have connect.php page :
<?php 


$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$connection = mysql_select_db('swaminarayan',$con);
mysql_select_db("swaminarayan", $con);
?>

Comment: and my table name is 'hotel' in mysql dabatase.

Comment: My answer already contains a connection to the database, you just need to fill in your details. Note that as of PHP 5.5.0, `mysql_connect()` is deprecated so you're better off using the `mysqli` alternatives.

Comment: I have another fields too to display simultaniously from this table 'hotel' along with retrieve the list of hotel ids from my database and show the corresponding images.
But, I did tried , it relay error till now. 
Anything, to help me , out of this, I do not have much experience in php. But need to complete my project asap. 
Only little time left for me to do it. Please, Help me.

Comment: @SwamiNarayan I've edited the answer, does it still not work for you?

Comment: This pulls images randomly. 
<?php
include 'connect.php'; 
$sql= "select * from hotel";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ ?>                    
<article><figure>
<?php
$directory = "../administrator/images/hotels/*/";
$images = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg");
$imgs = '';
foreach($images as $image){ $imgs[] = "$image"; }
shuffle($imgs);
$imgs = array_slice($imgs, 0, 1);
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
echo "<img src='$img'/> ";
}?>
</figure><div>
<h1><?php echo " ".$row['name']." ";?>
<span>Add<?php echo " ".$row['add']." ";?></span>
</div></article><?php }?>

Comment: I want to clear a bit what I Need is , I want to retrieve the list of hotel from my database ='swaminarayan' from tabel 'hotel' and show the corresponding images.( The images are in uploaded dynamically in my folder making sub-folder for each newly hotel added. 
Any help , please?

Comment: @SwamiNarayan You should put your latest code in the question, rather than in the comments. Also, try the code in my answer and let me know if you have any problems with it.

Comment: I did used your code. But it shows nothing error, and do not retrieve images from relevant folder.

Comment: !
I did used your code, Nothings error display. And It do not pull any images. Mean, there is no any image is display. Code i use here: 
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'swaminarayan');
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT hotel_id, name FROM hotel");
$directory = "../administrator/images/hotels/";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

<?php
$id = $row['hotel_id'];
    $images = glob("$directory/$id/*.jpg");
    
    sort($images);
    //display images
    foreach ($images as $img) {
        echo "<img src='$img' height='150' width='150' /> ";
    }?>

Comment: I used your code, 
But, no images are displayed. 
Neither error. Please, help me out of this.

Comment: @SwamiNarayan I have added some code to help you with debugging

Comment: Dear Tom Fench :
The following error is display: Select returned 3 rows. Globbing for images in No images found Globbing for images in No images found Globbing for images in No images found.
I'v already told, I have many fields in my table 'hotel'. Folder that will creates in each new hotel entry takes names from name and hotel_address fields from table 'hotel', not according to id. [Means, the folder name will be created as :  Hotel ABC, Palma De mallorca ( and the image path will be as ( Hotel ABC, Palma De mallorca/ demo.jpg). So, here I want to pull image according to newly created folder.

Comment: This means that `realpath()` is returning `FALSE`. So maybe your directory `$search_dir` does not exist. You should add your directory structure to the question.

Comment: Yes , the directory is creates , when i add new hotel , Lets say: Hotel ABC from admin backend, the directory will creates using 2 fields from table 'hotel' : name and hotel_address. For example Hotel ABC(as hotel name from 'name' field) and New York,USA (as hotel's address from hotel_address field). And Image will save inside newly created folder ( Hotel ABC, New York USA) as (Hotel ABCNew York, USA/test.jpg ).

Comment: Thank you so much, Tom Fenech! 
It work all well.
Now I just want to display only 1 Picture under respective hotel.
It displaying all images from folder.

Comment: Thank you so much, Tom Fenech! It work all well. Now I just want to display only 1 Picture under respective hotel. It displaying all images from folder.
Help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. If you want something different, you should edit your question.